# alerts "First Name cannot be empty" and others by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Im trying to do a frontent Mentor challenge [active-stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72hIC.jpg) -- link for the image

And what i want to do is to show that errors that appears when i click the button "Claim your free trial".

I learned some javascript and i know that i can use "onclick" and then the function etc, but in this case im not sure how to do it, because i learned to use "onclick" function in the same place i that i am clicking. In this case, you click on the button but the message appears in the other boxes. Can someone help? Html code below, thanks!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/css/style.css">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Intro component with sign up form</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Learn to code by watching others</h1>
    <p class="text1">
      See how experienced developers solve problems in real-time. Watching scripted tutorials is great,
      but understanding how developers think is invaluable.
    </p>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="tryit">
      <strong>Try it free 7 days</strong> then $20/mo. thereafter
    </section>
    <section class="form">
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name"></input> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"></input> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Adress"></input> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password"></input>
        <input class="claim" type="submit" value="CLAIM YOUR FREE TRAIL"></input>
      </form>
      <p class="terms1">By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <a class="terms2" href="#">Terms and Services</a></p>
    </section>
  </main>
  
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="https://github.com/LucasBinho" target="_blank">Lucas Passos</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: inputs should have name attributes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Never heard of </input> before. Perhaps you mean <input/>?

Comment: im using vscode toby, and it works well so far this way